# How to use modulo in if condition wit global counter in jmeter

Tags: if-statement, jmeter, counter, modulo

How it is possible to use module operator in Jmeter If Controller to call request only after some amount of requests.

Answer (score 3):

1. You can track the current iteration of Thread Group using `${__jm__Thread Group__idx}` [pre-defined variable](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#predefinedvars)
2. You can use [__jexl3()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__jexl3) function in the If Controller's condition to run its children only after iteration N, example syntax:

   ```
   ${__jexl3(${__jm__Thread Group__idx} > 9,)}
   ```

   Demo:

   [image]

   More information: [6 Tips for JMeter If Controller Usage](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/six-tips-for-jmeter-if-controller-usage)

Answer (score 0):

It is possible with following statement in If Controller:

```
${__javaScript(${__counter(FALSE,)}%2 == 0)}
```

[image]

Comment: You may avoid using javaScript. It's better to switch to groovy or jexl3 function